# Deduplication of data using multiple columns in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I need to deduplicate a table where the rows aren't exact matches but where there is a set of logical criteria that would determine if two rows are duplicates. Example matching criteria: first 10 characters of `address` column match AND `salePrice` column is an exact match AND `closeDate` falls within an 8 day range.

Using those criteria, rows 2 & 3 are duplicates, and rows 10 & 11 are duplicates, in this dataset:

```
                                      address           city        county     houseSize lotSize salePrice closeDate pricePerFoot DOM
1                              1224 Hawkhurst Place     San Jose  Santa Clara      2022    3724    847500   7/24/17          419  50
2                                1224 Marionola Way       PINOLE Contra Costa      1228    1000    390000    7/9/18          318  41
3                                 1224 Marionola Wy       PINOLE Contra Costa      1228    1000    390000    7/3/18          318  NA
4                           1224 Rockledge Ln Apt 8 WALNUT CREEK Contra Costa      1054       0    374000   6/21/18          355   6
5                        1224 Singingwood Ct. Apt 3 WALNUT CREEK Contra Costa      1054       0    370000   9/26/18          351   6
6                             1225 Mente Linda Loop     Milpitas  Santa Clara      1371     435    800000  10/23/17          584  29
7                         1225 Oak Grove Avenue, Apt1   Burlingame    San Mateo      1814   10425   1498000  11/19/18          826  11
8                         1225 Singingwood Ct Apt 2 WALNUT CREEK Contra Costa       733       0    290000   7/12/18          341  19
9                         1225 Singingwood Ct Apt 4 WALNUT CREEK Contra Costa       733       0    290000   5/30/18          396   5
10                           1226 Creekside Way, Apt 5     Milpitas  Santa Clara      1522    1524   1015000  11/30/17          667   2
11                      1226 Creekside Way  , Apt 5     Milpitas  Santa Clara      1522    1524   1015000  11/30/17          667  NA
12                       1226 El Camino Real , Unit 201   Burlingame    San Mateo      1640   12912   1450000  10/18/18          884  12
```

I can't quite wrap my head around how to get there. It's not tough to see the duplicates with the human eye, but doing that for 40,000+ records makes me want to find a more elegant solution.

I've used the following on a dataset that doesn't include apartment numbers:

```
data <- distinct(data, tolower(substr(data$address,1,10)), salePrice, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

but this runs into trouble where the first 15+ characters of `address` match, but the apartment number at the end is different, as in rows 8 & 9 in the sample data.

Edit: to answer a request for `deput` - is this what you need?

```
    structure(list(address = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1224 Hawkhurst Place", 
"1224 Marionola Way", "1224 Marionola Wy", "1224 Rockledge Ln Apt 8", 
"1224 Singingwood Ct. Apt 3", "1225 Mente Linda Loop", "1225 Oak Grove Avenue, #1", 
"1225 Singingwood Ct Apt 2", "1225 Singingwood Ct Apt 4", "1226 Creekside Way  , Apt 5", 
"1226 Creekside Way, #5", "1226 El Camino Real , #201", "1226 Hawkhurst Place", 
"1226 Nestwood Way", "1226 Shelter Bay Ave, Mill Valley, CA 94941-3020", 
"1227 Chantel Way", "1227 Culet Ranch Rd", "1227 Shelter Bay Ave, Mill Valley, CA 94941-3086"
), class = "factor"), salePrice = c(847500L, 390000L, 390000L, 
374000L, 370000L, 800000L), closeDate = structure(c(13L, 15L, 
14L, 11L, 17L, 3L), .Label = c("10/18/18", "10/2/18", "10/23/17", 
"11/19/18", "11/30/17", "12/14/18", "12/21/17", "4/21/17", "4/23/18", 
"5/30/18", "6/21/18", "7/12/18", "7/24/17", "7/3/18", "7/9/18", 
"8/22/17", "9/26/18"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I would create an extra column of TRUE/FALSE that checks all of those conditions, then filter based on that new column

Comment: @RAB How would that work when you have to compare each row to every other row?

Comment: Can you add `dput` of your dataframe ?

Comment: @RonakShah Let me know if the edit adds what you were looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit #2: Found a solution

I was able to deal with dates that were close but not exact by creating a new column `dateGroup` with a letter value based on a defined range (e.g. `saleDate` between 1/1/2017 and 1/30/2017 is assigned `splitGroup` "a"). Then I used `data <- distinct(data, tolower(substr(data$address,1,10)), salePrice, splitGroup, .keep_all = TRUE)` to weed out duplicates that fell in the same date range.

To catch any duplicates that may have straddled two date ranges, I ran that twice with slightly different date range definitions.

Answer (score 0):

We could use the `duplicated` within `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   filter(!duplicated(cbind(substr(address, 1, 10), salePrice)))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Do you see a way to include the date proximity match as well? i.e. `closeDate` within 8 days of the matching record. Also, this seems very similar to the example I gave above: `data <- distinct(data, tolower(substr(data$address,1,10)), salePrice, .keep_all = TRUE)` .  What would be the primary difference?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of your code.  For some reason the 8 days difference you mentioned for those rows are not matching.  Can you please check